# How many days elapsed of the current year

Tags: php

I want to get number of days elapsed from the current years Jan 1st to today date. I am making a unique id and I want to use it as part of the id. I want number to fixed to three digits with leading zeros. Plz help.

e.g.

Today : 2012-2-27
Then number of days elapsed is 057.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_pad(date("z"), 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the 'z' argument to the `date` function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, then `printf` to print the leading zeroes

```
$day_of_the_year = date( 'z' );
printf( '%03d', $day_of_the_year );
```

Comment: How did I miss that!@#$. Thanks a lot for showing me. I did read the manual but didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$startDate = "2012-01-01";
$today = "2012-2-27";

$diff = abs(strtotime($today) - strtotime($startDate ));

$days = floor(($diff/(60*60*24));
if($days < 100) {
   echo "0".$days;
} else {
   echo $days;
}
```

You can get the difference of days the by following function also:

```
function dateDiff ($d1, $d2) {
// Return the number of days between the two dates:

  return round(abs(strtotime($d1)-strtotime($d2))/86400);

}  // end function dateDiff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = new \DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Prague'));
$first_day_of_year = new \DateTime($now->format('Y').'-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Prague'));

var_dump($first_day_of_year->diff($now)->format('%a'));
```

today is 2014-10-13, returns 285